Scrape reddit post and comments
I'm trying to scrape Reddit posts and comments using Node.js and Cheerio, but I'm not getting the expected results. Here’s a brief overview of my setup and the issues I’m facing.
Setup:
Node.js: v14.17.0
Cheerio: v1.0.0-rc.10
Request-Promise: v4.2.6
Code:
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/';


rp(url)
  .then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    let posts = [];

    $('div.Post').each((i, element) => {
      let title = $(element).find('h3').text();

      let commentsLink = $(element).find('a[data-click-id="comments"]').attr('href');

      posts.push({ title, commentsLink });
    });

    console.log(posts);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });


What is the expected result?

If you look at the content retrieved from the site using your code you'll see that Reddit is blocking your request.
You need to evaluate the dynamic content on the page and at least appear to be a browser. You can do this using Puppeteer.
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36');
  
  await page.goto('https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/');
  
  await page.waitForSelector('h1');

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    // Get all articles on page.
    //
    // ! Without pagination there will just be the top three articles.
    //
    const articles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('article'));
    // Extract content from each article.
    //
    // ! You can get some text but it's just a summary of the article, not full content.
    //
    const content = articles.map(article => {
        return {
            title: article.querySelector('a').innerText
        }
    });

    return content;
  });
  
  console.log(data);
  
  await browser.close();
})();

Sample output:
[
  { title: 'WTF Wednesday (June 19, 2024)' },
  {
    title: 'Your /r/javascript recap for the week of June 10 - June 16, 2024'
  },
  { title: 'Announcing TypeScript 5.5' }
]


